# When setting Full screen with navigation bar and status bar fitsystemwindows is ignored

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-styles

I want the background of screen(login screen background is just a gradient) to be shown behind transparent toolbar and transparent navigationbar but the paddings needs to be added manually. Currently I add padding to toolbar 20dp to make it look like it has too but the soulution should be to use fitsystemwindows on container and on toolbar, but it doesn't work, because we set flags programatically and i think it overrides them. Does anybody have a solution. I tried with styles and it works but the navigation bar isn't completly transparent it has transparent black border the only thing that i found that worked was if i set flags programatically. Any ideas?

Actvity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_blue_to_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />  <!-- Current solution for padding because fitsystemwindows doesn't work-->
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT** *Added screenshots*
This is how it is without padding:
[image: No padding]

And with padding.

[image: With padding]

Comment: What is your expected output and current output can u share screenshot for  both

Comment: Test case change `LinearLayout` with `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: I'm sorry, here you go, screenshots of desired result. I hide the content because it is sensitive :/ but you can clearly see what it is that i want to accomplish

Comment: Tried with Coordinator still doesn't work :( @NileshRathod

Comment: Can u share the style for this activity

Comment: It doesn't use any :/, because I don't want to use transclucent colors.
On other screens i use this:

    <style name="TransparentAppThemeLight" parent="AppThemeLight">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: do  you want your bottom navar transpant or not

Comment: yes, but without transparent black bar :)

Comment: Can you share screen shot for expected result my friend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181462/discussion-between-winterchilly-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

> Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/nilesh"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> **Original**  answer
>
> Activity

```
public class InventarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_statusbar_color));
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventario);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nilesh");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }


}
```

**EDIT**

> Activity

```
public class InventarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, true);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            );
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, false);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventario);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nilesh");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }
    private void setWindowFlag(final int bits, boolean on) {
        Window win = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }

}
```

> Custom theme

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you but This isn't the desired result :/ look at the navigation bar. It needs to be COMPLETELY transparent.

Comment: This works but is it possible to achieve this only with styles?

Comment: @WinterChilly  i think know because in my previous answer it will not make completely transparent

Comment: This works even if you remove the styles from the activity ;) thats why I'm wondering if it is possible

Comment: @WinterChilly you can get all information about the flag that i used from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams

Comment: I meant what excatcly does setWindowFlag does, and what about             winParams.flags &= ~bits
etc.